# How to generate a starter angular2 project which uses jspm using angular cli?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, systemjs, jspm, es6-module-loader

```
ng new PROJECT_NAME
cd PROJECT_NAME
ng serve
```

the above commands compile and bundle using webpack, was wondering if there is an option to generate the starter project to use ststemjs/jspm instead.If not can you elaborate the steps to achieve so.

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell, no.

One of the underlying goals of the @angular/cli is to abstract the build process - as an end user of the cli, you shouldn't need to care what it is using under the hood to build and manage your dependencies. So, I highly doubt that the ability to select what build tool the cli uses in the background is a high priority item to implement - if the cli is doing its job correctly, you shouldn't need to care.

Comment: How do you proceed in such case; more than an yes/no answer, I was hoping to understand the steps from someone who have generated the proj using angular cli and are now using systemjs/jspm to load in browser.

Comment: Do you know how to use and configure systemjs/jspm?  then you can add your system js configuration right alongside the existing angular cli configuration, but just use systemjs to launch your application. If you don't know how to configure system js, then you'll have to learn that first

Comment: Note that honestly, the only thing that really marks a project as an angular cli project is the angular-cli.json configuration (and i guess the npm scripts that point to the cli commands and angular cli in package.json).  As such, if you wanted to, you could manually switch to a different build system - you just have to manually set it up (as if the angular cli configuration wasn't there).

Comment: Yes I  understand how to create a webpack project or systemjs+jspm project from scratch but here I can't follow how `@angular/core` is being loaded as I don't see any `webpack.config.js` being generated

Comment: the webpack configuration is (intentionally) hidden - the angular-cli.json represents the configuration for the angular cli. In the newest version(s) of the cli, there is an ng eject option (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/eject) to get at the webpack configuration if you need to